# ¿Cómo puedo multiplicar dos partes de un XML pertenecientes a dos nodos distintos?

Tags: xml, xslt

Tengo el siguiente documento XML:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kFqRnGmVlNid-BqPUo3vYAcSQdzDKBUq/view?usp=sharing

Me piden que, partiendo de ese documento, obtenga la siguiente salida en html:
[image]

No he tenido problema con ninguna parte, excepto por la columna Factura con IVA de la tabla de Ventas. Para obtener este dato, tengo que multiplicar el precio por el IVA que se le aplica a ese producto. El IVA que se le aplica se encuentra en la parte de los proveedores, y el precio en la parte de las facturas.

El documento XSLT que tengo por ahora es el siguiente:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j85BEntg8WMOJGsg4tCVQxewXJ8Sl8xJ/view?usp=sharing

Muchas gracias de antemano por la ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si declaras

```
<xsl:key name="iva-de-proveedor" match="proveedor/iva" use="../@codigo"/>
```

en the archivo XSLT, en la columna puedes utilizar

```
<td><xsl:value-of select="@precio + @precio * key('iva-de-proveedor', @proveedor) div 100"/></td>
```

para utilizar el iva.

Comment: Genial, muchas gracias por tu ayuda :)